# Amp with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amp-html, google-amp

I was learning AMP with rails using following links

https://coderwall.com/p/wpyasq/how-to-create-an-amp-page-for-your-dynamic-content-in-rails

I Have cloned a sample app using following links

https://github.com/ProGM/rails-google-amp-example

The application is very simple it just include one show page.

So when i hit

```
http://localhost:3000/articles/1
```

It goes to Articles controller Show action, takes only one request.

When i hit

```
http://localhost:3000/articles/1.amp
```

It takes 4 request. Am unable to find the reason.

[image]

Note: If i replace

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp>
```

to

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
```

It takes only one request.

Help will be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: please share your source code.

Comment: https://github.com/ProGM/rails-google-amp-example
exact same